# wkhtmltoimage does not show gridlines of highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, symfony, highcharts, wkhtmltoimage

I'm using symfony to generate a [simple highcharts graph](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/gridlinewidth/), but wkhtmltoimage does not show the gridlines properly:

[image: wkhtmltoimage highcharts graph]

My `knp_snappy.image` config is the following:

```
options:
        encoding:           UTF-8
        format:             svg
        width:              0
        enable-smart-width: true
        zoom:               3
```

and I have added the following options to the graph:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
                shadow: false,
                animation:false,
                enableMouseTracking: false
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
If i use wkhtmltopdf the output is correct..

Comment: Are you explicitly setting a gridLineWidth? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth Does anything change if you try to set it to something different than 1?

Comment: Yes, i have change the size and the color but nothing has changed

Comment: Could you show the whole chart config? Also, disable [chart.animation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation).

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/GalassoBelka/sw9nzrt1) is my entire example, and i have no animation, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have done!

The problem is with the perfectly horizontal (or vertical) path, probably is related with [old's webkit bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135321)

Than my solution is to edit the horizontal (and vertical) line of the grid to make it not perfectly horizontal-vertical.

```
//fix bug of horizontal-vertical path (TODO: check all series)
yaxis = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-yaxis-grid')[0].childNodes;
for (i=0; i<yaxis.length; i++) {
    if (yaxis[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'path') {
        d = yaxis[i].getAttribute('d').split(' ')[2];
        yaxis[i].setAttribute('d', yaxis[i].getAttribute('d').replace(d, parseInt(d)+0.000001));
    }
}

xaxis = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-xaxis-grid')[0].childNodes;
for (i=0; i<yaxis.length; i++) {
    if (yaxis[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'path') {
        d = yaxis[i].getAttribute('d').split(' ')[1];
        yaxis[i].setAttribute('d', yaxis[i].getAttribute('d').replace(d, parseInt(d)+0.000001));
    }
}
```

For example, with the following horizontal path i have to edit the first occurrency of the number 264.5, 213.5, 163

```
<g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid ">
    <path d="M 77 264.5 L 413 264.5"></path>
    <path d="M 77 213.5 L 413 213.5"></path>
    <path d="M 77 163.5 L 413 163.5"></path>
</g>
```

to obtain the following non-horizontal lines

```
<g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid ">
    <path d="M 77 264.500001 L 413 264.5"></path>
    <path d="M 77 213.500001 L 413 213.5"></path>
    <path d="M 77 163.500001 L 413 163.5"></path>
</g>
```